# Capybara rails testing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, integration-testing

I'm new at rails. I'm using a copybara gem for testing the devise. Here is a test code

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTasksTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'Should create a new user' do
    visit root_url
    click_link 'Sign up'
    fill_in "Email", with: 'capybaratest@test.ru'
    fill_in "Password", with: 'capybara'
    fill_in "Password confirmation", with: 'capybara'
    click_button 'Sign up'
    within("h1") do
      assert has_content?(user.email)
    end
  end
end
```

After running a test i've got an error:

> undefined local variable or method `user'

How should I write the test correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing the creation of a new user and expecting its email to be displayed after the sign up. So, the `user` variable is not defined and for that reason you are getting this error. Try the following:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTasksTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'Should create a new user' do
    visit root_url
    click_link 'Sign up'
    fill_in "Email", with: 'capybaratest@test.ru'
    fill_in "Password", with: 'capybara'
    fill_in "Password confirmation", with: 'capybara'
    click_button 'Sign up'
    within("h1") do
      assert has_content?('capybaratest@test.ru')
    end
  end
end
```

Just to clarify, one situation that you would use the `user` variable is i.e the login flow: before you start the test you would create a valid user and set the `user` variable with this new user... in this way you would be able to fill in email/password fields with email and password used to create the user, and finally check if it displays i.e `"Welcome #{user.name}"`.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful for me :)